# Azure Data Factory - 'variables' is not a recognized function

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are using an Azure SQL Database sink in a Copy Activity.

The requirement is for us to execute a stored procedure here via the "Pre-Copy Script" property of the Sink. We are using Dynamic Content, passing in a "ProcessName" parameter. As you can see, we have a ProcessName variable, and it is used in a call to @concat() to build the stored procedure string for this Sink property.

However, any time we use the variables collection in Dynamic Content, we get this warning as shown in the image. The warning states:

> 'variables' is not a recognized function

Is there a way to avoid having this "Warning" in the UI? It works fine, but it looks terrible. It appears everywhere we use variables, not just in this case.

[image: Add Dynamic Content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pipeline parameters instead of variables and calling it as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

You are most likely going to have to change your logic to do this. But if it works fine as it is, I wouldn't mind changing logic or code just to stop seeing the warning in the UI.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hi! Does this mean that, personally, you would change the code to avoid the UI warning, or you wouldn't? Thanks!

Comment: I chalked this up to a glitch/defect in the product, and kept my code as-is. Thank you!

Comment: im still not really understasnding the use case for variables vs parameters